# first time installation settings set up android

Tags: android

I have a program using android and I would like a few tips on how to save the first time installation settings. I would think a writing to a file on the device for the first time install and then a check to see if there is anything there and then reading it for the rest of the application. is there a better way of doing this or has anyone got a tutorial on how to read and write to an android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SharedPreference to save your first time.......